# Animation of refresh button in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

I am trying to rotate my refresh button 360 degrees. Rotation is working fine, but when the image  rotates it showing large and when the animation is off it is show is smaller size. I am not sure why this happening? I would like to have the image animation in the same size.

I have the refresh button on the actionbar.

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.ylg.maps.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_Refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="1000"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_Refresh"/>
```

**My Rotation Anim:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" > 
</rotate>

</set>
```

**My Progress Bar XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
android:layout_width="5dp"
android:layout_height="5dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/refresh" />
```

Here is how I use it in my MainActivity class this is called when the refresh button is pressed.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress, null);
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_rotate);
rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
iv.startAnimation(rotation);
refreshItem.setActionView(iv);
```

here is the screen shot:

**With out animation:**

[image]

**When I press the refresh button : The button is big.**

[image]

Not sure how to fix this problem? Can anybody help me fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got solution for jumping icon / bigger icon. This solution will be useful for people who are using stock actionbar.

Refresh item in menu.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
android:actionLayout="@layout/refresh_action_view"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>
```

In MainActivity: call the below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.orders, menu);

   final Menu m = menu;
   refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
   refreshItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {   
         m.performIdentifierAction(refreshItem.getItemId(), 0);
         rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.clockwise_refresh);
         rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
      }
   });

return true;

}
```

And to animate call the following where ever required:

```
 refreshItem.getActionView().startAnimation(rotation);
```

To stop animation:

```
 refreshItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
```

Thats it. Animation will be smooth.. without any jump or oversizing..

Hope this helps others!

Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same problem as you did but your solution didn't worked for me. After some digging I discovered I was using icons with the wrong sizes, changing the icons fixed the problem for me.

Comment: `style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"` what is that? It's not allowed there

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to look exactly like the ActionButton, you need to use the exact same attributes then. From a quick glance to the Holo theme styles, here's what I found:

```
    <style name="Widget.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">56dip</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
    </style>
```

What this means is that you probably need to add left and right padding to your imageview (I am not sure whether the minWidth and height is necessary). Alternatively, you can simply set the above mentioned style to your ImageView:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
```

Your choice!

Comment: I am already setting the style. The default Android Action bar style.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, didn't notice that. There is a possibility though that the phone's attr points to another style. You can try to use style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle" instead, just to make sure you use the corect style.

Comment: Oh, wait! The style should not go to the menu item, it should go the to layout file (refresh_action_view I guess in your case).

Comment: I tried what ever is given in the question I had problem with size of image and jumping.. So after couple of hours of research and trial and error. I figured out the answered solution. it is working perfectly now.

Comment: @TheDevMan What was your solution?